# Crear esquema en mongoose en tiempo ejecución

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Buenas, Estoy ususando [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) con [mongoose](/questions/tagged/mongoose) y quiero hacer que se creen o extender esquemas en mongoose en tiempo ejecución. Que el esquema se construya definido por una información enviada desde el cliente, es decir, quiero agregarle más campos indefinidos a un documento o esquema que ya está definido. Por ejemplo, tengo el siguiente esquema:

```
var user_schema = new Schema({
    Nombre: String,
    Apellido: String
});
```

Pero quiero que el cliente tenga la facilidad de agregar más campos al formulario si lo desea, como por ejemplo "Cumple Años", entonces que se genere guarde el documento de la siguiente forma:

```
var user_schema = new Schema({
    Nombre: String,
    Apellido: String,
    Cumple_años: Date,
});
```

No sé si me explico pero ¿Alguien sabe como recrear un esquema en mongoose en tiempo de ejecución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma es tener esquemas "bases" de las cuales extender mediante builders. Por ejemplo:

```
class SchemaBuilder {

  constructor(baseSchema) {
    this.schema = baseSchema;
  }

  addField(name, opts) {
    this.schema[name] = {
      type: opts.type,
      required: opts.required || false
    }
    if(opts.default) {
      this.schema[name].default = opts.default;
    }
  }

  addValidatorFor(fieldName, obj) {
    this.schema[fieldName].validate = {
      validator: obj.validator,
      message: obj.errorMessage
    }
  }

  build() {
    return this.schema;
  }
}

module.exports = SchemaBuilder;
```

A este builder le pasaríamos por constructor el esquema base del cual extenderá el nuevo esquema:

```
const userSchema = require('../schemas/user');


const builder = new SchemaBuilder(userSchema);
```

> Los esquemas "base" son simples objetos (`{}`) que servirán para crear nuevos esquemas en base a ellos. Una vez extendidos los esquemas, se hace uso de `mongoose#model` para crear el esquema en mongoose.

Una vez que le pasamos el esquema base, podemos añadir campos con sus respectivos validadores si es el caso:

```
builder.addField('email', {
  type: String,
  required: true
});
builder.addValidatorFor('email', {
  validator: function(field) {
    return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(field);
  },
  errorMessage: 'Email inválido'
});
```

Y finalmente creamos el modelo en mongoose del nuevo esquema creado:

```
const ExtUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(builder.build());
mongoose.model('ExtendedUser', ExtUserSchema);
```

Comment: ¡Genial hermano! tenía rato buscando esto y nada... Muchas gracias por tu respuesta bien explicada @MitsuG, bendiciones!...

Comment: Si te sirvió mi respuesta considera marcarla como correcta :)